# Keyboard isn't visible when clicking text input of UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uikeyboard

when selecting a text field on a uiwebview the keyboard isn't visible.
i check the keyboard frame when getting the notice that the keyboard will appear.  there IS a frame.

i think it has something to do with the constraints i have to do the layout of the views.

what is the correct (most simple) way to adjust those constraints (if that is indeed the issue) to "make room" for the keyboard?

curiously the little bar that typically appears with the keyboard is visible ... the one that looks like this :

```
| <  >          Done  |
```

this is getting frustrating so any help is appreciated as usual :)

i should probably add that the setup i have is a uiscrollview that contains uiwebviews.  the scrolling is turned off in the scrollview so as not to get things too confused.  everything seems to work as intended .. except this keyboard issue.

Comment: Why the keyboard isn't visible?

Comment: the default one that appears from bottom of screen

Comment: WOW.  this was just a problem in the simulator.  had to go to uncheck HArdware -> Keyboard -> Connect HArdware Keyboard.

Comment: found that solution elsewhere on here!

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the same problem before as you have now.

I believe it is triggered automatically by the iOS simulator when accidentally *typing with your **real keyboard*** in the text field instead of **"*clicking on the keyboard*"**  in the simulator.

To resolve this issue, simply go to the iOS simulator, navigate to the Menu bar:

"**Hardware** > **Keyboard**" and uncheck "**Connect to external keyboard**".
The problem should now be solved.

Comment: this helps me so much, thank youuu very much

Answer (score 0):

This can happens in 2 cases:

1. in simulator
2. if your iPhone or iPad use external keyboard